# Rotation with Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, rotation, keylistener, graphics2d

I am currently experimenting with the Graphics2D and the KeyListener, and I am currently testing out rotating objects (in this case a pentagon). Now, it's working in the sense that it rotates, except it is supposed to rotate by 1 radian each time VK_RIGHT or VK_LEFT are pressed.

However, currently it does that for the first key press only. From then on, it creates a pattern of rotating it by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... and so on radians each time (the nth keypress rotates it by nth radians) instead of just 1 radian per keypress.

Creating the JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class Main {

        public Main() {
            JFrame window = new JFrame("Rotating Hexagons");
            window.setSize(800,600);
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setResizable(false);
            window.setContentPane(new RotatingHexagon());
            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[]args) {
            new Main();
        }

    }
```

RotatingHexagon Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class RotatingHexagon extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    private Polygon poly;

    private int[] xpoints = { 0, -10, -7, 7, 10 };
    private int[] ypoints = { -10, -2, 10, 10, -2 };

    private int rotation = 0;

    public RotatingHexagon() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void init() {
        poly = new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, xpoints.length);

        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        init();

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int width = getSize().width;
        int height = getSize().height;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawString(rotation + " radians", 10, 20);

        g2d.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
        g2d.scale(20, 20);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation));

        g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 100, 100));
        g2d.fill(poly);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.draw(poly);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        switch(k.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            rotation--;
            if (rotation < 0) rotation = 359;
            repaint();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            rotation++;
            if (rotation > 360) rotation = 0;
            repaint();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {}

}
```

I really don't have any idea why it isn't just rotating 1 radian each time, so any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is calling the init() function in the paint() method again and again. So the KeyListener is added multiple times, causing that it is called multiple times, incrementing your counter more every time you press the key.

Move it to the constructor:

```
public RotatingHexagon() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    addKeyListener(this);
}

public void init() {
    poly = new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, xpoints.length);        
}
```

Andy

Answer (score 1):

You should probally just use a persistant AffineTransform to do the rotation. They are a lot more powerfull.

I also saw several issues in your code, you are calling the init method each frame - this could be 60 times per second. In this you are adding a new keylistener each frame. You are also creating a new polygon which would slow down performance.

I've made some changes to your code and and i've used AffineTransforms as an example. Have a look and see if this helps.

```
package com.joey.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AffineTransformTest extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    private Polygon poly;

    private int[] xpoints = { 0, -10, -7, 7, 10 };
    private int[] ypoints = { -10, -2, 10, 10, -2 };

    private int rotation = 0;
    AffineTransform transform;
    AffineTransform rotationTransform;
    AffineTransform translateTransform;

    public AffineTransformTest() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();

        //Do Init here - no point in creating new polygon each frame.
        //It also adds the key listener each time
        init();
        updateTransforms();
    }

    public void init() {
        poly = new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, xpoints.length);
        transform = new AffineTransform();
        rotationTransform = new AffineTransform();
        translateTransform = new AffineTransform();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    //Use Paint Compoent
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //Always call super to clear the screen
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int width = getSize().width;
        int height = getSize().height;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawString(rotation + " radians", 10, 20);


        //Store old transform so we can apply it
        AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
        //Add Transform and move polygon
        g2d.setTransform(transform);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 100, 100));
        g2d.fill(poly);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.draw(poly);
        g2d.setTransform(old);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        switch(k.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            rotation--;
            if (rotation < 0) rotation = 359;
            repaint();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            rotation++;
            if (rotation > 360) rotation = 0;
            repaint();
            break;
        }
        updateTransforms();
    }

    public void updateTransforms(){
        //Resets transform to rotation
        rotationTransform.setToRotation(Math.toRadians(rotation));
        translateTransform.setToTranslation(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);

        //Chain the transforms (Note order matters)
        transform.setToIdentity();
        transform.concatenate(translateTransform);
        transform.concatenate(rotationTransform);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {}


    public static void main(String input[]){
        JFrame f= new JFrame("AffineTransform");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(100, 100);
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(new AffineTransformTest());
        f.show();

    }
}
```